# Is it possible to suppress syntax error for function-like imports in vscode

Tags: ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code

In VScode whenever I am using the function-like import proposal that is supported by webpack I get a syntax error. Is there a way to suppress the syntax error message or make the js debugger recognize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`import` expressions should be supported in VSCode 1.14. You can try this out today with the current [vscode  insiders build](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders)

In older versions of VS Code, you can suppress this error by adding:

```
"javascript.validate.enable": false
```

to your workspace or user settings. This is not ideal since it suppresses all errors in JavaScript files so I recommend trying out VSCode 1.14